# How to Add a new field to nested jsonb object in Node-Postgres using parameters?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

There is a table A and jsonb field 'context', it looks like:

```
{
  "variable": {},
  "other_stuff": {}
}
```

I need to add a new property to 'varialbe' every time i run query. So It should do smth like:

query1

```
{
  "variable": {
      "var1": "var1Value"
},
  "other_stuff": {}
}
```

query2

```
{
  "variable": {
      "var1": "var1Value1",
      "var2": "var1Value2"
},
  "other_stuff": {}
}
```

And if variable already has this field, it should replace it.
I run this sql, and it works:

```
let sql  =  UPDATE chatbots.A SET context = context || jsonb_set(context, '{variable, var1}', 'var1Value1')
```

It works but when i need to replace 'var1' and 'var1Value1' by parameters ($1 and $2) - it doesn't work (in node-postgres)

I realized that i can replace second parameter by

```
 to_jsonb($2::text)
```

But what should i do with the first one?

My javascript code

```
    async setUsersVariables(params: {users: ChatUser[], variable_name: string, variable_value: string}) {
        const {users, variable_name, variable_value} = params
        if (!users.length) return false

        let sql = "UPDATE chatbots.A SET context = context || jsonb_set(context, '{variable, $1}', to_jsonb($2)::text) WHERE chat_user_id IN ( "

        const parsedUsers = users.map(e=> e?.chat_user_id)

        let sqlParams: any[] = [variable_name, variable_value]
        let idx = 3;

        ({ sql, idx, params: sqlParams } = addSqlArrayParams(sql, parsedUsers, idx, sqlParams));

        sql += ` RETURNING chat_id, chat_user_id, platform, platform_user_id`;

        const filteredUsers: any = (await this.pool.query(sql, sqlParams)).rows

        return filteredUsers
}
```

Comment: can you add your `javascript` code to answer?

Comment: @Amin Taghikhani
 done!